# How do I enable PHP execution on the default directory?

Tags: php, rhel5, redhat

I'm setting up a server with Plesk, and we'd like to be able to provide a publicly-accessible copy of phpMyAdmin.

I was able to determine where it could go:

```
/var/www/vhosts/default/httpsdocs
```

However, it's serving phpMyAdmin as the actual PHP files, not as executed PHP.

What's the best/correct way to enable PHP execution on that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't write, what webserver do you use. I assume it is Apache running on RHEL5

First, you must check, if php module is installed and loaded into apache and properly configured.

You wrote, that apache return files intead of executing them. This is default action for apache if apache doesn't know, what to do with special file type. In default RHEL apache config, php is loaded from file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` contains line `Include conf.d/*.conf`, which includes all files from `conf.d` dir. These lines from `php.conf` should be uncommented:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Second, you must check, if SELinux protection doesn't deny any requests. If SELinux deny access to some files from apache, you will se `403 Forbidden` error in your browser. In `/var/log/audit/audit.log` you will se some `avc:  denied` messages. You should read `man httpd_selinux` manpage. Files from directory `/var/www/vhosts/default/httpsdocs` should be labeled with `httpd_sys_content_t` label (you should execute `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t`). To make this change premament (to survice filestytem relabel), you should execute also `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/vhosts/default/httpsdocs(/.*)?`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a  directive to control/configure that directory